# How can I use other icons as the ones in the SymbolIcon enumeration?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I use SymbolIcon controls in my UWP app, which is very handy. But I see other apps use more symbols than are provided by the enumeration. How can I use them as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `SymbolIcon` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx) is a standard set of common icons. But they are actually shortcuts to characters in the `Segoe MDL2 Assets` font. If you open up Word you can select that font. If you then go to Insert - Symbols - Symbol - More Symbols … you see all the icons available in that font. If you click on one of those icons, you see also the character code of that icon (e.g. the Headset icon is E95B).

To use those others, you can use the `FontIcon` control and set the `Glyph` property. There are different ways to set it, depending on where you use it. For the example Headset icon with character code E95B you would do it this way:

In XAML you can define it like this:

```
<FontIcon x:Name="SampleFontIcon" Glyph="&#xE95B;" FontSize="200" />
```

You need to preceed the value by &#x and close it with a semicolumn. And as you see you can determine the size with the `FontSize` attribute.
If you want to set the value in C# code, you do it like this:

```
SampleFontIcon.Glyph = "\uE95B";
```

I once wanted to debug the values and came up with this method to show the value:

```
private string getUnicodeString(string input)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
    if (bytes.Length == 0) return "";
    string output = "\\u";
    for (int i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        output += string.Format("{0:X}", bytes[i]);
    return output;
}
```

Now you can convert a glyph value back to something you're familiar with in code.

Answer (score 2):

Martin's answer is absolutely right, just two points from me.

If you want to see all possible Segoe icons, better than Word is just run built-in Windows app 'Character Map', where you select 'Segoe MDL2 Assets' and you see codes and icons.

You can also use this icons even in basic TextBlock, you just have to change FontFamily:

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
           Text="&#xE700;"
           ..... />
```